# play ogg files in tkinter without pygame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

Is there any other solution except `pygame` to play `ogg` files in `tkinter`?

I faced lots of problem installing `pygame` in windows, specially for recent version of `python`. Just like to know if there is any alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pyglet` module.

```
import pyglet
media = pyglet.media.load('file.ogg')
media.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

- To install pyglet in windows, in cmd run `pip install pyglet`
- If avbin driver doesnt work, you can get it from : http://avbin.github.io/AVbin/Download.html